# Best settings for efficient eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

What are the best settings to ensure that eclipse is as fast and efficient as possible? I understand that
eclipse requires a lot of memory and with the following it still is not that efficient

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms512M
-Xmx2048M
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optimizing Eclipse for Android development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654607/optimizing-eclipse-for-android-development)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the size and resources of your projects. 
There is no ideal setting for the Eclipse IDE.

Holds resources by default and will adding as needed.